# How to stop an async thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an async task. I initialise my task using this variable

```
     fhr_alg = new AddStringTask();
```

I want to use a start and stop button, so that when i stop it, the thread cancels and a new thread starts on clicking the start button. 
I use

```
    fhr_alg.cancel(true);
```

for cancelling the task. In my onclick event for start button, when I write

```
    fhr_alg.execute;
```

it gives an error showing that the task is still running. I used isCancelled() in doInBackground but nothing happens. I need help in fixing this issue.

Here is my code sor start and stop button

```
    k.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(task!=null)
            {
                task.cancel(true);
            }
                                                              try {
                w.clearView();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

         }
         });


     j.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View arg0) {   


             flag = true;

                Thread tt = new Thread()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try{
                            sleep(100);
                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }finally{

                            AddStringTask task = new AddStringTask();
                            task.execute();                 
                        }
                    }
                };

                tt.start(); 

                 int m=112;
                 String s=""+m;         
                 if(flag)
                 w.loadUrl("javascript:callJS(\""+s+"\")"); 
                 }
```

It gives me an error saying

```
    Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Comment: Are you aware that an `AsyncTask` object can be used only once?

Comment: I'm not sure about android but this is often called doing an Interrupt. Hope it helps you google the right terms.

Comment: I set Interrubt enable true, but doesnt work.
@rajesh, so how can I initialise the object again? I tried by setting it null and reinitialise it, but it doesnt work properly.

Comment: You have to create the object again. What do you mean by "doesnt work properly"?

Comment: It would help if you provided the code for your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I realize the problem is completely about reinitializing the object. I tried to reinitialize the object using
new MyTask().execute();
But how to I cancel it now? I mean how do I get reference to my asynctask running?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you call task.canle(true); inside the Listener.

Try to create a sub in your Activity class like

```
public void cancleTask(){
    task.canle(true);
}
```

and call this sub in your Listener.